# Why do the minions suddenly get faster?

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes, when I'm clearing minion waves and moving to the next tower, the minions suddenly run significantly faster out of nowhere, as if something sped them up. Only thing is, I have no sort of passive or aura that would make them do such a thing.

Is there a reason for this occurring, or am I the only one who has seen this occur?

Comment: IIRC they go faster if they are a) out of enemy vision and b) quite far away from the next enemy. It seems to occur at random and I haven't found an official answer.

Comment: I also can't find any official sources, but with some experimenting, I've found out that they tend to exhibit such behaviour when you are tailgating these minions. I think it is to catch up with the rest of the wave, but it also tend to happen randomly if you have high ping or lags badly.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably because of a lag-spike. The minion objects in-game have moved ahead, but because of the lag your video shows them at the same place. Once it syncs, they move to the new position.

Comment: I favour the lag hypothesis as well. I remember that happening a lot when I had a bad wi-fi, a lot less now I'm wired.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody put this in an answer yet... and I have come to the same conclusion.

Periodically minions will 'appear' to move really quickly without any sort of buff assistance.  This is because your game has become slightly out of sync and it is trying to quickly sync up the minion positions.  You will notice this less with a more stable connection.